# Discussão sobre arquitetura de software

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, apache-cordova, arquitetura-de-software

Eu estou reescrevendo uma aplicação para melhor estruturação da mesma e me surgiram algumas dúvidas.

A aplicação é um sistema de gerenciamento de apostas de futebol e conta com um app web para o gerenciamente e um app mobile para as apostas serem feitas. Então, esta aplicação atualmente é usada por três clientes diferentes e certamente mais usarão no futuro.

Eu gostaria que, diferente do cenário atual, eu não precisasse repetir código pra cada uma das aplicações. Eu gostaria de ter um domínio e identificar qual usuário está fazendo uso do aplicação baseado no subdomínio usado. Por exemplo: **usuario1.meudominio.com**. Então eu saberia que o usuário à acessar o sistema é o usuário 1 e usaria um token para acessar dados do mesmo em um banco comum à todos os usuários diferenciando os registros por tokens.

**Seria arriscado misturar dados?**

Eu também pensei em fazer realmente três sistemas separados e até cheguei à fazer o rascunho na imagem abaixo. O **Banco API** é uma API que vai me fornecer dados de partidas, times, campeonatos e etc. 
Eu imaginei o **Banco Master** como sendo o banco que tem todos os dados em comuns entre todos as diferentes instâncias do sistema, no caso seria tudo que vai vir da API. E os outros três bancos sendo os bancos de cada uma das instâncias. Abri este tópico para ouvir opiniões e compartilhar experiências de como eu posso implementar da melhor forma esta arquitetura.

**O que posso mudar?**

Agradeço à todos que puderem contribuir.

**Obs**: Pretendo usar PHP + CodeIgniter para desenvolver o sistema web e o app mobile será escrito com Apache Cordova e o banco usado será MySQL.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Guilherme, vc está publicando a ideia do seu app. Recomendo ediar a pergunta de modo a proteger sua ideia e continuar deixando sua dúvida escclarecida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legal sua maturidade em enxergar conflitos de responsabilidades entre projetos/softwares. Espero conseguir usar essa sua desconfiança para te recomendar uma proposta de arquitetura.

> **Identificação e separação de responsabilidades**

Identifique os serviços de sua **solução**. Mas tente enxergar apenas o negócio de cada uma, e fique cego para parte tecnológica - como códigos, dominios, bancos de dados, etc.

- **Administrador da plataforma** - criar clientes, gerir acessos, planos, dashboards, etc;
- **Clientes** - cada cliente será um *clienteN.seudominio.com.br*.

Cada um desses dois é um projeto independente. Não compartilham códigos, classes, bancos de dados, nada. Isso pq elas devem ter autonomia. Sua administração deve funcionar mesmo se não houver nenhum cliente, e seus clientes devem funcionar mesmo se vc tirar toda sua adminstração do ar - web e banco de dados.

> **Como as aplicações - administração e clientes - se comunicam?**

Em uma primeira analisada, eu faria da seguinte maneira:

1. Toda atualização de plataforma que é feita da administração para o cliente deve ser feita via *Message Queue*.
2. Toda informação que a plataforma deve coletar do cliente:

   - Algumas informações, o cliente é quem irá informar suas atualizações à administração, via *Message Queue*.
   - Outra, mais *real time*,  administração deverá consumir uma API do cliente.

**IMPORTANTE**: Uma aplicação - seja admin ou cliente - nunca deve acessar diretamente o banco de dados uma da outra. Isso cria uma super acoplagem, e é uma péssima prática.

> **Seria arriscado misturar dados?**

**SIM**. E voce já sabia disso, mas perguntou por prudência, e isso é saudável: +1 pra você.

Cada cliente seu deve ser uma instância totalmente isolada. Cada um de seus clientes deve ter uma instância da aplicação web/api, sua própria instância de banco de dados, e sua própria área de *storage file* - não me vá colocar arquivos dos cliente na famosa pasta `upload` junto aos códigos da sua aplicação, heim?.

> **Devo repetir código para cada uma das aplicações?**

Óbviou que **NÃO**. Todos os seus clientes devem rodar o mesmíssimo código fonte, com a última atualização e tudo mais. E esse código deve ser totalmente parametrizável. Desde configurar cores, títulos, imagens, logos, também como credenciais, connectionstrings, storage locations, e por ultimos *toggles* para habilitar ou não *features*, recursos, etc.

> **One Server to rule them all?**

Vi no seu desenho que vc tem um servidor hospedado de tudo - aplicação web, api, bancos de dados, etc. **Isso não é legal**. O ideal é um servidor por responsabilidade. Um para hospedar aplicações web - preferencialmente um para sua administração e outro para os clientes  - outro para sua base de dados, e outro para seu storage file. Esse tipo de *approche* chamase *Cloud First*, desenvolva sua solução para que seja já moldada para ser hospedada em nuvem.

Comment: Só agora eu pude ver a resposta e agradeço pela mesma. Você poderia me recomendar o que estudar para desenvolver aplicações com esse aspecto? Pesquisei algumas coisas por conta própria mas quanto mais melhor. Agradeço novamente. Abraço!

Comment: Bom, vou jogar algumas temas. Leia cada um superficialmente e depois aprofunde de acordo com necessidades. Domain Driven Design, Bounded Context, CQRS, Event Source, Message Queue.